# How do I set all Outlook reminders from other people to 0 minutes?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

If someone sends me a calendar invite, the person who sent the invite sets when the reminder appears. I would like to always see every reminder at 0 minutes. How do I permanently change all reminders set by other people?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, we can receive reminders in 0 min by setting the default reminder of the calendar(via File>Options>Calendar>under Calendar options>select Default reminders, and choose 0 minutes). This applies to all the existing appointments and meetings in the calendar. Save this setting for future appointments and meetings. But this will not affect the original reminder of the meeting you received. I'm afraid we need to change it manually.
[image]

Comment: That setting affects the default reminder for events I make. It does not affect other people's events. I'm on Mac in case there are any subtle differences between the outlook versions.

Comment: I've done a lot of tests on this and didn't find a method to do it. I'm afraid it can't be implemented directly on Outlook for Mac.

Comment: I have the same problem in Mac - AFAIK, Christy is correct - there is NO way to set a default reminder time on meetings you accept from other people - its ALWAYS 15 mins, then you have to change it manually - it's a real pain, but most Microsoft s/w is, so hey